# how to delete database table row depending upon the row count

Tags: java, mysql, database

I want to delete table rows from xyz table where row count should be greater than 10, but I don't have any column that holds row position. I don't want to add additional column such as Id. Here is my table structure:

```
name(as text)  subject(as text)  filename(as text)
```

and here is my query which deletes entire table

```
delete from questions where (select Count(*) from questions)  between  10 and 20
```

I am not getting what to write instead of `(select Count(*) from questions)`

any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would work:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT TOP 10 name FROM table)
```

This is assuming that name is unique.

Comment: If only you used LIMIT instead of TOP. :) Question is tagged MySQL.

Comment: thanks it works but, in sqlite I had to write this thing instead of SELECT TOP:  SELECT * FROM Table_Name LIMIT 5

Comment: Ah, yes.  I've been spending too much time using SQL Server... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution might be to maintain a timestamp on each record and drop the oldest one when a new one comes in.  It seems bizarre that you have so little need for the data you've persisted.  I wonder about your requirements and your design.

Answer (score 0):

Create a replica table with same scheme say test2

```
insert into test2 select * from test limit 10

delete from test;

insert into test select * from test2;
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not provide a row id, but there seems to be a workaround using session variables, as posted in the answer to this thread: [Equivalent of Oracle’s RowID in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728413/equivalent-of-oracles-rowid-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Making 2 assumptions: name is you id column and you want to sort by name.

One way to do it would be to:

```
DELETE FROM Xyz WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM Xyz ORDER BY name LIMIT 10);
```

But that will likely just give you:

```
ERROR 1235 (42000): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
```

As a workaround to that you can use a temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp SELECT * FROM Xyz ORDER BY name LIMIT 10;
DELETE FROM Xyz WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM temp);
DROP TABLE temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is weird.

1) Why don't you want an additional column?
2) Which rows do you want to delete? Unless the choice is made on name, subject or filename, you *will* need an additional column.
2a) If which rows are deleted does not matter, you can simply stop inserting after 10 rows. You can also have a CHECK constraint which enforces this for you, though I'm not sure if MySQL supports such an *advanced* construct.
3) Is the number really 10? If so, are you sure a database is the storage you need for this? I gotta go with @duffymo here, this smells of bad design.