# Removing Duplicate Entries in MySQL Database without a primary Key

Tags: mysql, database, duplicates, primary-key, distinct

I've received a reasonably big MySQL database with a lot of duplicates. Around a third of the database are duplicates. It is also **missing** a primary key.

The structure of the database is so:

```
unique_id | field01 | field02 | field03 | field04 | ...... | field26 | field27 |
```

Now while the unique_id is supposed to be, well, unique; there are a lot of duplicates.

Also, for a set of rows belonging to copies of a particular unique_id, the remaining columns may or may not be the same. For example, looking at unique_id 'id_1' below, field01 is same in both the instances, but field02 & field03 are not.

I would like to remove the repetitions and have only one copy of each unique_id survive. **It does not matter which one survives.**

Example:

```
id_1 | abc  | dfd  | NULL | ... | def | 
id_2 | abc  | daf  | ghi  | ... | 12a |
id_1 | abc  | xyz  | jkl  | ... | def |
id_4 | aaa  | bbb  | NULL | ... | def |
id_3 | NULL | bbb  | NULL | ... | 123 |
id_5 | 1e3  | NULL | NULL | ... | def |
id_3 | aaa  | bbb  | fds  | ... | def |
id_9 | awa  | bbb  | NULL | ... | 910 |
```

Should become:

```
id_1 | abc  | dfd  | NULL | ... | def | 
id_2 | abc  | daf  | ghi  | ... | 12a |
id_4 | aaa  | bbb  | NULL | ... | def |
id_3 | NULL | bbb  | NULL | ... | 123 |
id_5 | 1e3  | NULL | NULL | ... | def |
id_9 | awa  | bbb  | NULL | ... | 910 |
```

Or this is also fine:

```
id_2 | abc  | daf  | ghi  | ... | 12a |
id_1 | abc  | xyz  | jkl  | ... | def |
id_4 | aaa  | bbb  | NULL | ... | def |
id_5 | 1e3  | NULL | NULL | ... | def |
id_3 | aaa  | bbb  | fds  | ... | def |
id_9 | awa  | bbb  | NULL | ... | 910 |
```

Once this is done, I would need to set unique_is as the primary key.

Please advice the best and accurate way to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want duplication check only on unique_id column?

Comment: Please refer to this thread you will get some insights about deleting duplicate values :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728413/equivalent-of-oracles-rowid-in-mysql

Answer (score 2):

You could add a unique index in your table, ignoring all errors, and let MySql delete all duplicated rows (except one) for you:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE your_table ADD UNIQUE INDEX dupidx (unique_id)
```

but if you still get an error, even if you use IGNORE clause, try this:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ENGINE MyISAM;
ALTER TABLE IGNORE your_table ADD UNIQUE INDEX dupidx (unique_id);
ALTER TABLE your_table ENGINE InnoDB;
```

If you are just interested in showing your data, keeping just one row for each duplicated id, you could use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
GROUP BY unique_id
```

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem, and this worked great for me:

```
CREATE TABLE newtable SELECT * FROM oldtable GROUP BY unique_id;
```

Then drop the oldtable, and rename the new table to the old table name

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
select unique_id, field01 , field02 , field03 from (table_name) group by unique_id having sum(unique_id)<1
```