# Delete row in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, jsp

I am building JSP application in which I want to do following operations on specific table

- Display Data
- Delete Data

I've done displaying data, however:

How can I delete a row in database if the table does not have any primary key ? (Delete operation does not depends on any value of that row)

Suppose here is may table -->> mytemp
Here is the data

```
Name | RollNo
ABC  |  98
XYZ  |  76
ABC  |  98
XYZ  |  76
```

There is no key in this table and i want to delete 3 rd record. How can i do this ?

Comment: `(Delete operation does not depends on any value of that row)` So, On what column('s) the delete operation depends on? How the user suppposed to choose the rows to delete from the displayed data?

Comment: You need someway to identify a row to delete or do anything with.... never mind the fact that it's scary you have no primary key....

Comment: try this post :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728413/equivalent-of-oracles-rowid-in-mysql

Comment: @JonClements I agree with you **"You need someway to identify a row to delete or do anything with"** , But how it works in GUI or IDE ??

Comment: 1) What does this mean - ___But how it works in GUI or IDE ??___, 2) do you really think it matters if you delete the third one or the first one? 3) Can you give a use-case as to where you will need such a thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can choose any available column you think most suitable: e.g.

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE column_name  = 'valuse'
```

without column_name you can delete all rows only.

`column_name` does not has to be primary key, but all rows with `column_name  = 'valuse'` will be deleted.

---

**EDIT**
     To delete:

```
  DELETE FROM table_name WHERE Name = 'ABC' AND  RollNo  = 98;
```

`Name` and `RollNo` may not be primary key.

Delete only third row:

```
DELETE FROM table_name  
WHERE ('ABC',98) IN ( SELECT TOP 1 Name, Rollno 
                      FROM table_name 
                      ORDER BY Name,RollNo DES)
```

Second way:  if TOP not works

```
DELETE FROM table_name  
WHERE ('ABC',98) IN ( SELECT  Name, Rollno 
                      FROM table_name 
                      ORDER BY Name,RollNo DES LIMT 1)
```

<del>**CAUTION**: it will delete one, which one I am not sure.</del>

Give it a try!!

Comment: It will also delete first row , and i dont want to delete the first row.

Comment: @Nishant Let me think some option

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete all records you can use

```
delete from TABLE_NAME
```

and if you have any difference in the rows in the DB you can add `where` clause as well
like

```
delete from TABLE_NAME where COL1=XXX AND/OR COL@ =YYY
```

etc...

```
delete from TABLE_NAME where RollNo= RollNo_HERE AND Name = 'NAME_HERE'
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DELETE t
FROM YourTable t
WHERE t.Name    = 'Selected Name'
  AND t.RollNo = 'Selected RollNo';
```

Comment: Thank you very much . If there are more than one row having same value , then they also got deleted , i dont want do like this.

Comment: @Nishant - Yes it would. However you can limit that adding `LIMIT n` to limit the number of rows deleted by n.

Comment: Thanks , suppose there are three records like **XYZ 98** , **ABC 98** ,**XYZ 98**,**XYZ 98** , I want to delete third record , How can i set limit over here ?

Comment: @Nishant But what is your condition in this case if it is `WHERE name = 'xyz' and no = 89` then you can put `limit 1` this will delete only one row, but it doesn't matter for you which row. Because rows has no significant order in the table. They are not stored in a specific order.