# Oracle ROWID in table definition MySQL conversion

Tags: mysql, oracle

```
  DOCID    NUMBER(38)                               NULL,
  TEXTKEY  ROWID                                    NULL, 
  CONSTRAINT SYS_IOT_TOP_107722
 PRIMARY KEY
 (TEXTKEY)
```

I'm trying to define a table like this in `MySql` from our old `Oracle` databases, and I am uncertain how to handle this extended `ROWID` in `MySql`.

**UPDATE**

This is some of the sample data:`AAAaRfAARAAACtcAAA` . It appears to following the extended key format as stated in the oracle docs. Ill try to use binary and see if it bombs.

Comment: For those of us who aren't really proficient in Oracle... Is `TEXTKEY` a mere storage or does it have some added functionality? (For the first case, a `BINARY` column is probably all you need.)

Comment: I've never used a `ROWID` type, but according to the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96524/c13datyp.htm#918) it will hold an actual address for the row. The docs then go on to talk about Physical vs. Logical ROWID types and my eyes glaze over pretty quickly. I agree with you about the `BINARY` type as far as converting the values verbatim from Oracle to MySQL goes, but that leaves the question of how the user deals with new rows once on MySQL.

Comment: Yes TextKey is just the name of the column. Also i am concerned about what is inserted I'll see if I can find some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar StackOverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728413/equivalent-of-oracles-rowid-in-mysql) that gives alternatives but not a direct "MySQL equivalent of ROWID" because there isn't any such thing.

All the column seems to be doing here is creating a unique identifier for the row, so you could use an `AUTO_INCREMENT` or GUID column instead.