# Update table without primary key

Tags: php, mysql

Im building a shop and each product has a unique set of attributes.

the product db looks like this:

```
products_id, relation_id, product_name, description, 
price, glass, shipping, img, cat, subcat, model
```

Since every product has several (~40) different attributes unique to that product only ive created a second table to store them.

```
products_id, att_name, att_val, att_head, att_standard, att_order
```

This works fine, because there will never be two unique rows.
The problem, however, is when i need to modify the attributes content.

using MySQL Workbench i can modify a row using something like

```
UPDATE product_attributes SET att_val='1500' WHERE products_id='112' AND att_head='threshold'
```

This however, doesn't seem to work when i update from my php script.

Is there an easy way to modify the table to support updating?

Im well aware of the stupidity not having an unique column. 
But im not sure how to make the two tables relate. 
Where should i store the unique id of the attributes?

Comment: You'll need to post your PHP code - the update should work just as well there as with any other client.

Comment: "*doesn't seem to work*"?  What *does* it "seem" to do instead?

Comment: about making two tables relate, did you consider `foreign keys`?

Comment: If you need to reference an ID but don't have one, treat it like Oracle's ROWID. Someone on stackoverflow posted a nice solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728413/equivalent-of-oracles-rowid-in-mysql

Answer (score 2):

One choice,

add a **primary key** "auto_incremented" into the `product_attributes` table...

```
ALTER TABLE `product_attributes` ADD  `id` INT( 10 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST
```

This **Id** is just for CRUD *(Create Read Update Delete)* task.

The only relation you can have between your two tables is the `products_id` wich allow you to have few `product_attributes` for one `product`

Comment: Sure but the products table will have no relation to that id?

Comment: No, it's just to allow CRUD on this table using this ID. The relation is `products_id`!

Comment: After trying for over an hour to avoid this situation, this is the correct answer. to be able to do CRUD tasks, i need to create an auto incremented id field.

Answer (score 0):

Since 1 product has more than 1 unique attributes that u store in a second table, you should use the ID of the table product and store it in the second table with the attributes.

Hope this is what u need?