# How do I translate SQLite ROWID to an equivelant mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sqlite

How do I translate the following to an equivelant mysql query?

```
'SELECT ROWID, keyword, value, ref FROM t ORDER BY ROWID'
```

I found this related link, but I'm not sure how to apply it to what I'm doing here: [Equivalent of Oracle’s RowID in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728413/equivalent-of-oracles-rowid-in-mysql)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent to `rowid` in MySQL.  `rowid` represents the physical location of the record, and that information is not available in MySQL.

The following may be sufficient for what you want:

```
select (@rn := @rn + 1) as rowid, keyword, value
from t cross join
     (select @rn := 0) const;
```

Although this query is not guaranteed to return the rows in physical order, in practice it would typically do so.  The `rowid` is just a sequential number in this case.