# How to delete a specific defect row via console

Tags: mysql, innodb

My server crashed due to a hardware failure and as a result saving to some tables causes a crash of MySQL. I'm using InnoDB and can't fix the tables. I want to try to remove some rows and maybe get some data back.

Is it possible to remove a specific row number or set of rows from a specific table via the mysql console? For instance, row 1300 of table X, or rows 1400 through 1500 of that same table?

Comment: Are you able to interact with that table at all without a crash? Selecting from it, describing it or getting a count of rows?

Comment: This might help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728413/equivalent-of-oracle-s-rowid-in-mysql

Comment: As far as i can say.. if i open it mysql crash, if i export it.. it crash. the only thing i didnt try was to remove the whole table. I tried now to with the example from the other question,- sadly not working that way he is also crashing `SQL SELECT @rowid:=@rowid+1 as rowid FROM blizzard_armory_urls, (SELECT @rowid:=5) as init ORDER BY id schlug fehl: Lost connection to MySQL server during query`  Sadly i think that was it. Thank you guys