# Converting Oracle query which has rowid and rownum to MySQL query

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have the below query in Oracle .
      How can I convert this to MySQL as we don't have rowid and rownum in MySQL?

```
update test_dalpu 
    set data_present ='true'
    where rowid
       in (select rowid from
              (select rowid
               from test_dalpu
               where EXP_TIME < current_date ORDER BY PRIORITY)
            where rownum <= 7 );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equivalent of Oracle’s RowID in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728413/equivalent-of-oracle-s-rowid-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Use `limit 7` instead of `rownum <=7`. And I don't think you need `rowid` here do you?