# Oracle SQL query to delete the all the tuples with duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Given the table **Seminar (SeminarNo,title,location)**,my SQL query is an attempt to delete the all the tuples with duplicate seminar ids, but im not sure where to go from here.it does not work.

```
   Delete from Seminar S
   where (
   Select * from Seminar 
   Group by seminarno
   Having count (seminarno)> 1 );
```

Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: The title says Oracle but the tag says MySQL. Which database are you actually using?

Comment: If all 3 columns of the table are duplicated you cannot achieve it using a single delete statement.Could you check the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728413/equivalent-of-oracle-s-rowid-in-mysql.

Comment: Tag your question properly!!!  If this is Oracle, why is the question tagged MySQL???  They're 2 completely different products.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like the following:

```sql
delete from Seminar
 where seminarno in (select seminarno
                       from Seminar
                      group by seminarno
                     having count(*) > 1)
```